# How to upgrade existing Cocos2d 3.0 project to 3.1 beta

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can I upgrade my current 3.0 project to 3.1 beta? I got the first step covered (download 3.1 beta!) but what then? I am afraid I would mess things up and I am not that familiar with XCode to get myself out of trouble.

Thank You

Comment: Are you using it in a SpriteBuilder project? In any case the APIs did not change to my understanding so it would be a simple overwrite of the cocos2d files. Then you would clean your project and delete the derived data just to be safe. And then normally it would be good to go. Always back up before doing changes like this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update old version of cocos2d [Update cocos2d](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/update-cocos2d-iphone-existing-project/)

Comment: 0: The info you linked look terribly old. 1: You should include all details in your answer. 2: In the 3.1 thread, I asked the same question and got a response - the forum is down at the moment, but the link to my question should be on this page: http://forum.cocos2d-iphone.org/t/cocos2d-3-1-is-out/13868/8 (iphone in the url might change to swift soon)